# removing all option of dropdown box in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i dynamically remove all options of a drop down box in javascript?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('id').options.length = 0;
```

or

```
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Yes, `options.length` works all the way back to 1996 and Netscape 2!

Comment: Absolute god send best and most dynamic answer I have found for this. Works in all browsers I have tried the latest chrome, IE and Firefox

Answer (score 5):

```
var select = document.getElementById('yourSelectBox');

while (select.firstChild) {
    select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: I get a weird flash in IE6 when

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `length` to 0 is probably the best way, but you can also do this:

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById("select");
var len = mySelect.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    mySelect.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: your solution rocks... It solved wat i had been struggling for 6 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="thing"><option>fdsjl</option></select>
<script>
var el = document.getElementById('thing');
el.innerHTML = '';

// or this

while ( el.firstChild ) {
   el.removeChild( el.firstChild )
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is innerHTML cross-browser safe?

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy using JavaScript and DOM:

```
while (selectBox.firstChild)
    selectBox.removeChild(selectBox.firstChild);
```

Comment: imageDropdownBox.options.length

Comment: yes - as @hunter said, options.length = 0 is a good way to unset all the options (Javascript array access like), and I voted his answer up for that. But unfortunately its not working that well on all browsers. If you expect older browsers then I thin DOM-level-1 is the best API.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution I was able to find is the following code (taken from this [article](http://www.somacon.com/p542.php)):

```
// Fast javascript function to clear all the options in an HTML select element
// Provide the id of the select element
// References to the old <select> object will become invalidated!
// This function returns a reference to the new select object.
function ClearOptionsFast(id)
{
    var selectObj = document.getElementById(id);
    var selectParentNode = selectObj.parentNode;
    var newSelectObj = selectObj.cloneNode(false); // Make a shallow copy
    selectParentNode.replaceChild(newSelectObj, selectObj);
    return newSelectObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simple and elegant way to do this:

```
for(var o of document.querySelectorAll('#id > option')) {
  o.remove()
}
```