# PHP - Dynamic Dropdown on Class value using JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdowns which full information from my SQL table. One dropdown consist of "Colors." The other dropdown consist of members in the specific colors. I already have them in the different optgroup based on their class value which is "color."

My goal is to have the user select "COLOR" and only the members in that class show up in the member dropdown.

Ex. I select Red on the first dropdown. Only members in "Red" will be available in the second dropdown.

Hopefully it can be down using JavaScript

SQL Table:

```html
+-----------+--------------+
| GroupName | MemberName   |
+-----------+--------------+
| Red       | Joe Bob      |
| Red       | Catherine    |
| Blue      | Tommy        |
| Orange    | John Razks   |
| Black     | Trevor Smith |
+-----------+--------------+

+--------+
| Color  |
+--------+
| Red    |
| Blue   |
| Orange |
| Black  |
+--------+
```

PHP Code:

```html
<?php
  $conn = mysqli_connect("#Connecting");
  if(!$conn){ die("Connection Failed".myslqi_connect_error()); }
  else{
    $color_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from Color order by Color ASC");
    $colors = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($color_result)){ $colors[] = $row['Color']; }
    $member_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT distinct MemberName,GroupName from Members order by MemberName ASC");
    $members = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($member_result)){
      if(!isset($members[$row['GroupName']])){ $members[$row['GroupName']] = array(); }
        $members[$row['GroupName']][] = $row; }
  }
?>
<form id=#blah>
Color:
<select id="committee" name="committee">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>
        <?php
            foreach($colors as $color){
              echo "<option value=\"".$color."\">".$color."</option>";
            }
         ?> 
            </select>
        </div>

    <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
    Individual: 
    <select name="senator" id="senator">
        <option value="">Select Individual</option>
        <?php
        foreach($members as $key => $member_group){
                echo "<optgroup class=\"".$key."\">";
                foreach($member_group as $val){
                    echo "<option value=\"".$val['MemberName']."\">".$val['MemberName']."</option>";
                }
                echo "</optgroup>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
 </div>
  </form>
 
  
  <form id=#id>
  Color:
  <select id="committee" name="committee">
<option value="">Select Color</option>
        <?php
            foreach($colors as $color){
              echo "<option value=\"".$color."\">".$color."</option>";
            }
         ?> 
            </select>
        </div>

    <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
    Individual: 
    <select name="senator" id="senator">
        <option value="">Select Individual</option>
        <?php
        foreach($members as $key => $member_group){
                echo "<optgroup class=".$key.">";
                foreach($member_group as $val){
                    echo "<option value=\"".$val['ValueName']."\">".$val['MemberName']."</option>";
                }
                echo "</optgroup>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
  </form>
```

Comment: hmm what about fill the option of a color with an array the members of the color? and onchange of the select add the options with [add](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp) and remove the others with [remove](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp).

Comment: @DeadMaster what happens if you add new color and members? Couldn't that have an affect and also can you present an example?

Comment: I will make you an answer with an example just wait a few min ;)

Comment: Greatly appreciate it @DeadMaster

Answer (score 0):

you can use this demo code which help you

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="firstmenu" name="City" onchange="select_other(this.value)">
<option value="Color1">Color1</option>
<option value="Color2">Color2</option>
<option value="Color3">Color3</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="secondmenu" name="zipCode">
<option value="Color1">Member1</option>
<option value="Color2">Member2</option>
<option value="Color3">Member3</option>
</select>

 <script>
 function select_other(value){
    $("#secondmenu").children('option').hide();
    $("#secondmenu").children("option[value^=" + value + "]").show();
    $("#secondmenu").children("option[value^=" + value + "]").attr('selected',true);
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Can this also work if I don't hardcore my id or option? Just use the variable that calls the id?

Comment: yes it will work, can you post your hmtl output data which i can understand your select option list

Comment: the script is iffy. if you go through the second time, it doesn't go to the right value like 1-1 2-2 3-3

Comment: this is just demo code and every time on change give you right value then need to action

Answer (score 0):

What would work is to fill the values of an option with the members and read them out in a new select, but it's easier with an example:

**HTML & PHP CODE**

Of course you can still use your array, but I just like to do it with the "while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))" way. Also It surely doesn't look nice, but that's not part of the question ;)

```
// on the color select add this onchange
<select id="color" onchange="setOptions(this.value)">
<?php
  $color_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from color ");
  while ($fetch_colors = mysqli_fetch_assoc($color_result)) {
    $color = $fetch_colors['color'];

    // This select is changed: WHERE GroupName='$color', 
    // so it just reads the members of the current color
    $member_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT distinct MemberName from Members  WHERE GroupName='$color' order by MemberName ASC");
    $memberstring = "";
    $i=1;
    $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($member_result);
    // Here just an string gets filled which will be the value of the option
    while ($fetch_member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($member_result)) {
      if ($count_rows==$i) {
        $memberstring.=$fetch_member["MemberName"];
      } else {
        $memberstring.=$fetch_member["MemberName"].",";
        $i++;
      }
    }
    // This is the option with the color and with the value as members
    echo "<option value=\"$memberstring\">".$color."</option>"; 
  }

 ?>
</select>

<select id="members">
 // In here the options will show up
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

So this is a pretty much simplified version of the javascript. Meaning, it just runs on every change of the color option. If you want to have a "clear" option you will have to 1. insert it into the select (also add a special value) 2. write an if in the javascript function, to check if the option is clear.

```
function setOptions(val) { 
  val = val.split(","); // val is now an array with all the members of the color
  document.getElementById('members').innerHTML = ""; // This clears all "old" members of the select
  var select = document.getElementById("members");

  for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { // Now for each Member in the array a new Option is created
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = val[i];
    select.add(option);
  }
}
```

More links:
[javascript add option](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp), 
[removing all options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618763/removing-all-option-of-dropdown-box-in-javascript)

If you have any questions, feel free to ask me in the comment section.

Comment: Oh and it _should_ work directly if you insert it in your code, but it could have some mistakes so i don't guarantee anything

Comment: Is the php code to replace my two select ones? What I'm asking is I still need my first php code right?

Comment: @catung555555 Not necessarily.. it surely doesn't look the same. But from the functionallity, I think it would replace it. It depends if you still need a few variables of the top php part or/and what you want to do afterwards.

Comment: could yo put a code of those into one webpage so I can see cause I'm not having any success